# How can I serializeArray with a structure based on key value?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, serializearray

I am creating an Array from a form via `serializeArray()` in jQuery:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
var formData = form.serializeArray();
```

If I output this with `alert(formData.toSource());` I get the result:

```
[{name:"form[username]", value:"1"}, {name:"form[email]", value:"1@12.sw"}, {name:"form[is_active]", value:"1"}, {name:"form[plainPassword][first]", value:""}, {name:"form[plainPassword][second]", value:""}, {name:"form[id]", value:"9"}, {name:"form[_token]", value:"Mk"}]
```

If I capture the data via Ajax to php with `$data = $request->request->get('data');`I get the following Array as a result:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "form[username]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "form[email]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "1@12.sw"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "form[is_active]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "form[plainPassword][first]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "form[plainPassword][second]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "form[id]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "form[_token]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(43) "Mk"
  }
}
```

The array that I would actually need is something like this:

```
  array(2) {
    ["form[username]"]=>
    string(14) "1"
    ["form[email]"]=>
    string(1) "1@12.sw"
    ["form[is_active]"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["form[plainPassword][first]"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["form[plainPassword][second]"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["form[id]"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["form[id]"]=>
    string(2) "Mk"
  }
```

So is it possible to actually serialize the Array differently? What is the best way to achieve the array I would need?

Comment: You would need to create that object structure by manually looping through the form elements. There's no built-in jQuery method to do it for you

Comment: Right, you would have to build the array you want manually in your js

Comment: Or you could manually parse data instead of using `$request->request->get()`. I guess this sends JSON ? Or as @LawrenceCherone proposed, with array_column: `array_combine(array_column($data, 'name'), array_column($data, 'value'));`

Comment: @AymDev This is solving my problem!

Comment: @AymDev Do you like to post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @Jarla I can't answer as your question is put on hold but thanks ! Maybe if it reopens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $i) { $newData[$i['name']] = $i['value']; }
```

$newData is now like you wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, there is no built-in way of doing so. You either have to loop through the array and build the object yourself, or more common, just use `.serialize()` and handle the parameter interpretation in php directly.